# How can the SFDX CLI force:source:push and pull commands be configured to retain the underlying metadata packages?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I was having some issues with a particular source push to a new scratch org and wanted to examine the underlying metadata based package that was being deployed to Salesforce. How can I see what the SFDX CLI was deploying with my `force:source:push` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SFDX_MDAPI_TEMP_DIR` [environment variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_cli_env_variables.htm) can be configured to retain the underlying metadata packages.

From the docs:

> Places the files (in metadata format) in the specified directory when you run some CLI commands, such as `force:source:<name>`. Retaining these files can be useful for several reasons. You can debug problems that occur during command execution. You can use the generated `package.xml` when running subsequent commands, or as a starting point for creating a manifest that includes all the metadata you care about.
> `SFDX_MDAPI_TEMP_DIR=/users/myName/myDXProject/metadata`

From a Windows command prompt:

```
SET SFDX_MDAPI_TEMP_DIR="C:\Development\SFDC\metadata\"
```

I'd avoid pointing it to a sub-directory of your current project if possible to keep it separate from the rest of the source.

Comment: whats the command in mac? nvm i found it ... its export