# SfdxError: An internal server error has occurred VS Code

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api, metadata, package.xml, visualstudiocode

I just purchased a new enterprise license with Salesforce and I connected my VS Code to the sandboxes and the production org. Every time I try to push the package.xml file I receive this error:

```
starting SFDX: Deploy Source to Org
10:46:04.214 sfdx force:source:deploy --manifest /Users/oliviaporter/Desktop/dev/manifest/package.xml --json --loglevel fatal
10:48:10.275 sfdx force:source:deploy --manifest /Users/oliviaporter/Desktop/dev/manifest/package.xml --json --loglevel fatal
 ended with exit code 1
SfdxError: 
<html>
<head><title>An internal server error has occurred</title></head>
<body>
```

If I manually make an Apex class or custom object in Salesforce I can pull it into VS Code with `SFDX: retrieve source in manifest from org`. But I can not create a new apex class in VS Code and do `SFDX: deploy source to org`. The same internal error message is returned.

I am sure the connection is correct (due to being able to successfully pull from the org into the IDE). I am thinking it is a whitelisting issue or a setting I am missing.

I have checked profile settings and API Enabled it true.

Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening?

My goal is to be able to update the package.xml so I can import 100 custom fields on the Account object. This felt like the easiest way to go about it.

manifest package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTestSuite</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
       <members>Account.MyCustomField1__c</members>
       <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>StaticResource</name>
    </types>
    <version>51.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: Do you see any more errors in setup -> deployment status after you deploy from vscode?

Comment: Try configuring the [`SFDX_MDAPI_TEMP_DIR` environment variable](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/319643/102). The should retain the resulting package zip file that gets created and will give you a chance to inspect what is being deployed.

Comment: @Raul I am having the same error, but I don't see anything on the Deployment Status page of the org. This seems to be the issue with CLI.

Comment: I fixed my problem by running these two commands sequential `sfdx update` and `sfdx plugins:update`.

Comment: @rahulgawale That worked thanks man!

Comment: @rahulgawale its worth posting your comment as an answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this problem by executing the below commands sequentially.

```
sfdx update
sfdx plugins:update
```